# Expand specific items in a treeview during filtering

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

Let's consider this tree data :

```
Root
|-v A1
| |-- textA
|
|-v B1
| |-- textB
```

When searching "A1" I want the A1 item NOT expanded (but expandable to see the children):

```
Root
|-> A1
```

When searching "textA" I want the A1 item expanded (to see the matched child):

```
Root
|-v A1
| |-- textA
```

The (standard) filtering provided by QSortFilterProxyModel works fine, but I don't find how to implement the "expand when needed" thing.

I tried some stupid code, and it didn't work:

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(
  int sourceRow,
  const QModelIndex &sourceParent
) const {
  bool result = QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);

  if (m_tree) {
  //   if (result)
       m_tree->expand(sourceParent);
  }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that the following solution might help you a bit.

I consider it a sane way to expand the items, if they are just few children having the name being searched for. An unresolved issue might be the folding of children, if one changes the search field. Type for example `C-0-0-0` in the search field to understand the behavior of my solution.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>


int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (auto i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        auto item = new QStandardItem(QString("A-%1").arg(i));
        model->appendRow(item);
        for (auto j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            auto item2 = new QStandardItem(QString("B-%1-%2").arg(i).arg(j));
            item->appendRow(item2);
            for (auto k=0; k<10; k++)
            {
                auto item3 = new QStandardItem(QString("C-%1-%2-%3").arg(i).arg(j).arg(k));
                item2->appendRow(item3);
            }
        }
    }

    auto proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyModel->setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true);
    auto view = new QTreeView;
    view->setModel(proxyModel);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(view);
    auto edit = new QLineEdit;
    frame->layout()->addWidget(edit);
    frame->show();
    QObject::connect(edit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](auto test) {
        proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(test);
        Qt::MatchFlags flags;
        flags.setFlag(Qt::MatchFlag::MatchStartsWith, true);
        flags.setFlag(Qt::MatchFlag::MatchWrap, true);
        flags.setFlag(Qt::MatchFlag::MatchRecursive, true);
        auto indexList=proxyModel->match(proxyModel->index(0,0), Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole, test, -1, flags);
        for (auto index : indexList)
        {
            auto expanderIndex = index.parent();
            while (expanderIndex.isValid())
            {
                view->expand(expanderIndex);
                expanderIndex = expanderIndex.parent();
            }

        }
        qDebug() << indexList.size();
    });
    app.exec();
}
```

**Improved Solution**

The following improved solution uses just the found indices by the model without the possible different searching for indices provided by `match`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include "MyProxyModel.h"

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (auto i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        auto item = new QStandardItem(QString("A-%1").arg(i));
        model->appendRow(item);
        for (auto j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            auto item2 = new QStandardItem(QString("B-%1-%2").arg(i).arg(j));
            item->appendRow(item2);
            for (auto k=0; k<10; k++)
            {
                auto item3 = new QStandardItem(QString("C-%1-%2-%3").arg(i).arg(j).arg(k));
                item2->appendRow(item3);
            }
        }
    }

    auto proxyModel = new MyProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyModel->setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true);
    auto view = new QTreeView;
    view->setModel(proxyModel);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(view);
    auto edit = new QLineEdit;
    frame->layout()->addWidget(edit);
    frame->show();
    QObject::connect(edit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](auto test) {
        proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(test);
        if (test == "") return;
        view->collapseAll();
        QList<QModelIndex> acceptedIndices = proxyModel->findIndices();
        for (auto index : acceptedIndices)
        {
            auto expanderIndex = index.parent();
            while (expanderIndex.isValid())
            {
                view->expand(expanderIndex);
                expanderIndex = expanderIndex.parent();
            }

        }
        qDebug() << acceptedIndices.size();
    });
    app.exec();
}
```

**MyProxyModel.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

class MyProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QList<QModelIndex> findIndices() const
    {
        QList<QModelIndex> ret;
        for (auto iter=0; iter < rowCount(); iter++)
        {
            auto childIndex = index(iter, 0, QModelIndex());
            ret << recursivelyFindIndices(childIndex);
        }
        return ret;
    }


    bool rowAccepted(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const
    {
        return filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
    }
private:
    QList<QModelIndex> recursivelyFindIndices(const QModelIndex& ind) const
    {
        QList<QModelIndex> ret;
        if (rowAccepted(ind.row(), ind.parent()))
        {
            ret << ind;
        }
        for (auto iter=0; iter<rowCount(ind); iter++)
        {
            ret << recursivelyFindIndices(index(iter, 0, ind));
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Comment: Well that kinda works, but you are forcing a second search/match here, and with different options than the first filtering. I'm wondering about performance issues here.

Comment: @Salamandar: Another option might to connect to the signals of `proxyModels`. If the model changes one can get all current indices, which can be separately being checked, if they match by calling `filterAcceptRows` externally.

Comment: @Salamandar: I improved my solution. Maybe that should fit your needs.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit but that works correctly ! I added a 'else' in recursivelyFindIndices, to recurse only if the node did not match.

Comment: @Salamandar: Good to hear. I also learned a lot by solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few suggestions to @Aleph0 answer:

1. **main.cpp** piece:

```cpp
        view->collapseAll();
        QList<QModelIndex> acceptedIndices = proxyModel->findIndices();
        for (auto index : acceptedIndices)
        {
            auto expanderIndex = index.parent();
            while (expanderIndex.isValid())
            {
                view->expand(expanderIndex);
                expanderIndex = expanderIndex.parent();
            }

        }
```

In order to prevent repeated expanding it may be good to check if *expanderIndex* was already expanded and stop going up. In worst case scenario it will save you from **O(n^2)** complexity (should be linear instead).

2. in a similar fashion, `MyProxyModel::findIndices` method can be implemented without recursion to speed things up (however, modern compilers should be smart enough to unroll it)